# adjusted R2 in plm package

Tags: r, plm

A colleague of me ran a code using the `plm` package from her local station a couple of months ago. Recently I redownloaded the package and ran exactly the same code. I noticed that the R<sup>2</sup> adjusted is slightly different.

Does someone know if the calculation of the adjusted R<sup>2</sup> has been updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First point to look at is the `NEWS` file of the package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/NEWS):

If you had a version before 1.5-15 and now after, this entry is relevant for you:

> - r.squared: adjusted R squared fixed

Comment: makes sense thank you, is it possible to know what has changed in the formula?

Comment: Very much so! It is open source, just compare the sources of the different versions.

Comment: @Helix123, your answers have been super helpful in the past and I don't know how else to get your attention, and I know this is kinda bad manners, but I want to ask if you would be so kind to look at this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351746/comparing-groups-in-repeated-measures-fe-models-with-a-nested-error-component Thanks!